# Upload image via ftp

Tags: image, file-upload

I want to store filename, filesize, etc. from images already on my server. My idea is to upload images via ftp and then store the data in mysql using php. Is that possible?

Comment: What do files already on your server have to do with FTP?

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "8.8.8.8";
$ftpUser = "user";
$ftpPass = "pass";
$conn = ftp_connect($servername) or die("<p style=\"color:red\">Error connecting to $servername </p>");

if(ftp_login($conn, $ftpUser, $ftpPass))
{
            ftp_put($conn_id, PATH_TO_REMOTE_FILE, $file)
}
```

assuming you're using PHP. After that, you can do whatever you want to do